neos migration from 7.3 to 8.3 generate this error
PHP binary might not exist or is not suitable for cli usage.
Command FLOW_ROOTPATH='/var/www/html/' FLOW_PATH_TEMPORARY_BASE='/tmp/Flow' FLOW_CONTEXT='Development/ddev' XDEBUG_CONFIG='idekey=FLOW_SUBREQUEST remote_port=9001' "/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.3" -c '/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini' didnt succeed.
i tried which php in iterm and put answer in setting.yaml
